# Controller didn't get more arguments laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to send two arguments and one request to controller with post request. This is the code where I send the arguments:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form1"  method="post" action="{{ route('shipment_view', $uniqueid, $category_name) }}" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And this is the controller where I'm sending the arguments:

```
    public function storeShipment(Request $request, $number, $category_name){

           $category = Category::where('category_name', $category_name)->first();
           $user = Auth::user();

           $item = new Item([

           'id' => $user->id,
           'category_id' => $category->id,
           'unq' => $number,
           'fullname' => $request->input('name'),
           ]);

           $item->save();
   }
```

But when I open the view it gives me error

```
ErrorException in NewShipmentController.php line 53:
Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\NewShipmentController::storeShipment()
```

Update:

My route function:

```
Route::post('/ship/preview/{number}',[
   'uses' => 'Controllerr@storeShipment',
    'as' => 'shipment_view'
]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: show your route for the same

Comment: @kapil.dev I update the question with route function, you can see

Comment: in your route there's only one variable and in function you are passing 2 , i think so that is causing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your route function with the below one

```
 Route::post('/ship/preview/{number}/{category_name}',[
   'uses' => 'Controllerr@storeShipment',
    'as' => 'shipment_view'
]);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes i know, but is there some way to pass in route only number variable, because I want my view to be like /ship/preview/{number}, i don't want /ship/preview/{number}/{category_name}

Comment: that's not possible, because function will expect to get 2 params, and it is getting only one

Comment: No u cant. You can run query if possible in controller to find category_name through number

Comment: if you dont wanna show cat_name then you can pass in through form, and access it from $request variable.

Comment: another way is to use encryption which will protect you primary ids like url/1/2 or url/3/4

Answer (score 0):

You can get the all the parameters through request it self But before this how you are defining the route

```
public function storeShipment(Request $request){

    $number = $request->number;
    $category_name = $request->number 
}
```